# After installing streamlit library on python, I am getting Attribute error : module 'plotly.graph_objs.layout.template.data' has no attribute 'Icicle'

Tags: python, attributes, attributeerror, streamlit

After installing streamlit library successfully on python but after running it,

I am getting Attribute error : module 'plotly.graph_objs.layout.template.data' has no attribute 'Icicle'

```
File "/home/appuser/venv/bin/streamlit", line 5, in <module>
    from streamlit.web.cli import main

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>

from streamlit.delta_generator import DeltaGenerator as _DeltaGenerator

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/delta_generator.py", line 75, in <module>

    from streamlit.elements.plotly_chart import PlotlyMixin

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/elements/plotly_chart.py", line 41, in <module>

    import streamlit.elements.lib.streamlit_plotly_theme

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/elements/lib/streamlit_plotly_theme.py", line 116, in <module>

    go.layout.template.data.Icicle(textfont=go.icicle.Textfont(color="white"))

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_plotly_utils/importers.py", line 39, in __getattr__

    raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: module 'plotly.graph_objs.layout.template.data' has no attribute 'Icicle'
```

Please tell how to git rid of this error

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
please  uninstall it and install streamlit 1.14.0

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with your plotly version being too old. Icicle charts were released in Plotly 5.0.0. So you need to install a version of plotly >= 5.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Not working to upgrade to 1.18.But works with 1.14.0

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and installing streamlit 1.14.0 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade to plotly 5.16.x.

Everything works as expected after upgrading to streamlit 1.26 and plotly 5.16.

```
pip install --upgrade streamlit
pip install --upgrade plotly
```